# What the effect of std::nth_element(a.begin(), a.end(), a.end())?

Tags: c++, stl

I read the description of `std::nth_element` at http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/nth_element.html

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void nth_element(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator nth,
                 RandomAccessIterator last);
```

Note that the preconditions are

1. [first, nth) is a valid range.
2. [nth, last) is a valid range.

My question is:

Is it valid to call `std::nth_element(a.begin(), a.end(), a.end())`? If so, what's its effect? It doesn't violate the preconditions above, anyway. Anywhere in the language standard (or other documents) stated that `nth` must be pointing to an element in `a`?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see the effect.

Comment: The result of a try is not reliable. It can be implementation dependent. Actually I wonder where is this issue specified in the standard of C++.

Comment: @updogliu The latest standard text is substantially the same as the SGI page you linked.

Comment: I hope that it is valid, otherwise we often need an extra check before calling `std::nth_element`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's valid and is probably, but not guaranteed by the standard, a null operation. With the given data, the two preconditions become:

```
[a.begin(), a.end()) is a valid range.
[a.end(), a.end()) is a valid range.
```

Which are both true, the second interval is empty though. From the standard 25.3.2/1:

> After nth_element the element in the position pointed to by nth is the
>   element that would be in that position if the whole range were sorted.
>   Also for any iterator i in the range [first, nth) and any iterator j
>   in the range [nth, last) it holds that: !(*i > *j) or comp(*j, *i) ==
>   false.

If the whole range was sorted the original `a.end()` would be at `a.end()` and for the second part the range `[nth, last)` is empty so there are no elements for which to evaluate the `!(*i > *j)` and `comp(*j, *i) == false` conditions.

Comment: Any reasoning to support the assertion?

Comment: @Potatoswatter I think you've helped me make my case in your comment on the other answers.

Comment: I think there is a typo. I see only `.end()`... no `.begin()`?

Comment: From my understanding of the standard, if think the preconditions are indeed met, but what are your arguments for stating that it is a null operation? If we take the requirements literally, this function is free to do anything in this case, including sorting or randomizing the entire range.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. I hope you can complete you answer by referring to the language standard, and explaining how to interpret it for this case. (I will accept it then, of coz.)

Comment: @Luc Yes, I think it is, as long as the complexity requirement is met (which means sorting is out ;) ) But you're right, the standard doesn't explicitly say that this is a null operation, although I think it will be on all implementations.

Comment: For what it's worth, paragraph 24.1/7 in the C++ standard confirms that the preconditions are met: `A range is a pair of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation. A range [i, i) is
an empty range; in general, a range [i, j) refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the one pointed to by i and up to but not including the one pointed to by j. Range [i, j) is valid if and only if j is reachable from i.`

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not valid because `nth` has to be within the range `[first, last)`.

Comment: Where is that requirement stated? It says "the element pointed to by the iterator nth is the same as the element that would be in that position…" but that requirement is simply null if it doesn't point to anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, `std::nth_element(a.begin(), a.end(), a.end())` is not valid -  it violates the second precondition, which requires that the `nth` iterator (the second argument) points to a valid element. `a.end()` doesn't point to a valid element though.

Comment: But, all ranges in C++ are half-open, and `[a, a)` is always an empty range. There isn't a clear requirement that `nth` be dereferenceable.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still deciding on whether to remove my answer, but I'm still not convinced it's wrong :)

Comment: Potatoswatter said my main concern.

Comment: Hm, after re-reading the C++ standard, I think Andreas is right. I'll explain in a comment to his answer. I didn't think that a range in which *both* iterators are `end()` is valid, I thought the first iterator of any range must point to a valid element.